# In AWS API Gateway, using Terraform, how do you create sub-collection resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform

I'm trying to create sub-collection resources under an existing resource, using a `GET` method; something like:

`/customers/{customerId}/accounts` or `/customers/{customerId}/accounts/{accountId}`

Using Terraform, I already managed to create my `customers` and `customers/{customerId}` resource – and they both work.

But when I try and add a resource under `customers/{customerId}`, I get the ever elusive `Missing Authentication Token` error (which I've come to learn is mostly just that API Gateway can't find the resource/implementation/lambda), even though everything seems to be wired-up correctly.

Example code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "customers" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.root_resource_id}"
  path_part = "customers"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "single-customer" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.customers.id}"
  path_part = "{customerId}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "customers-accounts" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.id}"
  parent_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.single-customer.id}"
  path_part = "accounts"
}

//----
// GET
//----
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "get-customers-accounts" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.customers-accounts.id}"
  http_method = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "get-customers-accounts-integration" {
  content_handling = "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my-api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.customers-accounts.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.get-customers-accounts.http_method}"
  type = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${var.region}:${var.account-id}:function:${var.customers-lambda}/invocations"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
}
```

Ideas? The lambda does exist, everything looks right in the console, and I did reselect the lambda function in the API Gateway console (there's a bug AWS cli where you'll get the `Missing Authentication Error` if you don't go in a manually reselect your lambda in the console).

#### UPDATES

As I mentioned, the Terraform code appears to work – no error there. The literal message I get from trying to access the endpoint is

```
{ message: "Missing Authentication Token" }
```

No logs are outputted. If I try and test the resource/endpoint via the API Gateway Test button, I get a `Malformed Lambda Proxy Response` – but that's misleading, as many valid, working endpoints generate that same message when being run from the Test button

Comment: Can you show us the codes which don't work? And show us the real error message, please.

Comment: As I mentioned, the Terraform code appears to work – no error there. The literal message I get from trying to access the endpoint is `{ message: "Missing Authentication Token" }`. No logs are outputted.
 
If I try and test the resource/endpoint via the API Gateway _Test_ button, I get a `Malformed Lambda Proxy Response` – but that's misleading, as many valid, working endpoints generate that same message when being run from the _Test_ button.

Comment: Could you confirm that terraform issue or API setting issue? If you manually create that API gateway, would you get the same error?

Comment: Have you looked at your cloudwatch logs? Missing Authentication Token is thrown either because there is actually a "Missing Authentication Token" when using IAM Auth or when its actually a 404. If you do like the Missing Authentication Token error, you can remap that error ta 404 using the recently launched gateway responses - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-api-gateway-enables-customization-of-error-responses/

Answer (score 0):

> { message: "Missing Authentication Token" }

I have encountered the same when tried to access the lambda via endpoint but later a day it works though I didn't modify any changes.

Check your lambda output or it might be a api-endpoint resolver issue.

**Note**: Make sure you had deployed api after creating `api_gateway` else you will get the same message.